# Is the bias-variance tradeoff consistent across all x values in a linear model?

Tags: regression, variance, linear-model, bias

I'm having trouble making the transition from the concept of bias of a single estimator to bias in a linear model. The clearest explanation I've found is this detailed [simulation of bias and variance](https://statisticallearning.org/bias-variance-tradeoff.html#using-simulation-to-estimate-bias-and-variance) which compares the bias and variance of four models at the point $x = .9$ for data whose true fit is quadratic. My question is, does it matter which point is chosen?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes, in the case of fitting a straight line to a parabola. At the points where the expected fitted line intersects the true parabola,  there is zero bias. The bias gets greater as you go farther away from the center of the $x$ data.  (Just draw a straight line over a parabola; the vertical difference between the two is the bias.)    In the case where you are fitting higher order polynomials to the parabola, the bias is 0 for all $x$, but the variance increases as you move away from the center of the $x$ data.

Comment: Thanks. That is where my thoughts were leading. So how is bias / variance evaluated for the full model? I'm trying to understand what seems to be to be a mismatch between discussion of bias / variance at the the model level and examples such as the one I linked to that consider only one $x$ value?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "full model." Assuming it is the true model, then there is no bias f you fit the full model.  If the true model is a special case of the the full model (eg, quadratic = true, cubic = full), then there is no bias.